# How to store parameters from $_REQUEST for later use

Tags: php, search, parameters, request

I have an html page with a form. In the form I have a search function and a delete function that will be available in each results’ row, in this way:

```
..<td><img src="delete.gif" style="cursor: pointer" onClick="javascript:delete();"></td>..

    <input type="submit"   value="search" onClick="javascript:search();">
```

In a . js file I have both functions passing the parameters  to a php file via jquery’s ajax function.

Let’s go to the php file:

There are no problems with the search function: I get the parameters by $_REQUEST and I do a select query.

By clicking delete.gif in the form, I get to the delete function. The query deletes the selected row and right after I need to call the search function so I can show the results without the deleted row.

And here comes the trouble: both functions use $_REQUEST to build the queries so when calling search function after deleting I have the delete parameters stored in  $_REQUEST.

How can I recover the search parameters I had in $_REQUEST in the first search so I can do that search again after deleting??

Here’s a glimpse of the delete function in the php file:

```
function deleteResult($_REQUEST['param1'],$_REQUEST['param2'], $_REQUEST['param3'])
{  
    $strSqlDelete = "DELETE FROM …"; // query working in database
    //here the connecting to the database code
        $result = search($_REQUEST['param1'],$_REQUEST['param2'], $_REQUEST['param3']);
        echo utf8_encode($result);
        exit();
}
```

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not too safe to use `$_REQUEST` superglobal. Use `$_POST` or `$_GET` depending on your method. To store something for later use use `$_SESSION` suberglobal array.

```
    session_start(); // In the beginning of your script

...

    $_SESSION['param1'] = $_REQUEST['param1'];
```

Then you can use `$_SESSION['param1']` anywhere else within your site even after page reloading.

Answer (score 0):

Store it in the local variables or you can store them into the cookies. So that you can use it as many times you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do that by javascript

it's prefer to delete this row by deleting it  instead of calling server side again to render the result again

now you save unwanted hit to server side

**FOR EXAMPLE**

```
// in JS
   function delete(this){
      $.ajax({}); // call ajax to delete from server side (php)<br>
      delete this row (tr);<br>
   }
```